# Size of $q$ in reductions from lattice problems to R-SIS

Tags: lattice-crypto, hardness-assumptions, sis

The [Short integer solution problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_integer_solution_problem) is parameterized by four values:

- $n$, the dimension of the vectors that must be added
- $m$, the number of samples (dimension of the solution)
- $\beta$, upper-bound for the length of the solution
- $q$, the modulus defining $\mathbb{Z}_q$

Usually, the reductions from lattice problems to $SIS_{n, m, q, \beta}$ have the following template:

> For any $m = poly(n)$ and $q \ge \beta \cdot \tilde{O}(\sqrt{n})$, solving
>   $SIS_{n, m, q, \beta}$ gives a solution to an approximate version of a
>   lattice problem with approximate factor $\gamma$ which is a function of $n$.

I was expecting something like that also for the ring version of SIS, namely, R-SIS, that works over a ring $R$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$. However, on [Peikert's survey on lattice crypto](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lattice-survey.pdf#page=32) , in the end of section 4.3.4, some reductions from $SVP_\gamma$ to $R$-$SIS$ are  cited, but no restriction on the values of $q$ are done.

So, do you know what are the lower bounds for $q$ in the reductions from lattice problems to $R$-$SIS$?